# Не применяется аудит

Tags: windows, логирование, group-policy, аудит

Не применяется политика аудита, спускаемая через GPO
В Default Domain Policy настроен аудит входа в систему
В gpresult видно применение этой политики
но при этом в выводе auditpol /get /category:* показывает, что аудита нет
и при этом не регистрируются 4625 eventid (неудачная попытка входа в систему)
что я делаю не так?
что интересно, что до определённого момента всё было хорошо и работало

если станция не в домене, то всё регистрируется
при помещении в OU, на которую не применяются никакие другие политики (отключено наследование) то 4625 тоже не регистрируется

Comment: В политике стоит делегирование `Компьютеры домена`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам
По невнимательности был включен И простой аудит И расширенный
[proof](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/advanced-security-auditing-faq#bkmk-2)